# Previous month in sql

Tags: database

I have sql, where I need to select data for this month and data for previous month. How to do extraction od previous month data?

In my block in `build()` functionI have this:

```
//...
if ($what == "en_flip_per_month"){

    list($m, $y) = statistics_data_for_block('monthname', 'year');

    $sql = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'nfd');
    $sql->addExpression('COUNT(nfd.nid)', 'counting');
    $sql->where("nfd.langcode='en'");
    $sql->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(nfd.created, '%M' ) = ".$m."");
    $sql->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(nfd.created, '%Y' ) = ".$y."");
    $sql->groupBy('nfd.langcode');
    $sql->orderBy('nfd.created', 'DESC');
}
//....
```

and in my .module file I have this:

```
function statistics_data_for_block($m='', $y=''){
    $month = '';
    $year = '';

    //current
    if ($m == "month"){
        $month = "MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    }
    if ($m == "monthname"){
        $month = "MONTHNAME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    }

    if ($y == 'year'){
        $year = "YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    }

    //... SOMETHING FOR PREVIOUS MONTH ...

    return array($month, $year);
}
```

So, I need a way to extract `MONTH`, `MONTHNAME` and `YEAR` of `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 month)`.

There was this one solution - use of `SET` and `DECLARE`, but how can it be done in Drupal 8 dynamic query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
Answer is pretty clever - just take first day of current month and subtract 15 minutes.

```
//PREVIOUS MONTH

//"month"
    $month = "MONTH(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))";
}

//"monthname"
    $month = "MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))";
}

//'year'
    $year = "YEAR(DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to Drupal, but this works on mySQL

```
MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```